# Ipad how do I double click in safari?

Tags: ipad, safari, click

So I'm experimenting with using an ipad with a keyboard to do "lite-weight things". I'm not exactly sure why.. I think it has something to do with wanting to get away from my work laptop and not wanting to carry another laptop around.

One problem I experienced today was when using a web interface that required me to double click in safari. I couldn't seem to get this working.

How do I double click in safari? Is double click behaviour better in another browser?
Also is it possible to right-click?

I have a pencil - that I tried using - but that didn't really help...

## References

- https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250495647

Comment: Your link to Apple support discussions is about the double-press of the side button to confirm Apple Pay, not double-click on a webpage.

Answer (score 1):

A double-click can be performed by tapping twice in quick succession. If the page zooms instead, the website has not correctly programmed the double-click functionality.

A right-click can be performed by tapping with two fingers.